# How can I use node.js in an ASPX project?

Tags: asp.net, node.js

I have 2 projects, one in Node.js and one in ASPX.

I want to use the node functionalities in an ASPX project/solution. How can I do that ? (making a fusion between them basically but in ASPX).

Now you ask.me ... "WHY don't you do it the other way around ?" , that's because in my company all the webpages are programmed in aspx and we are trying to implement Node.js on them ... and I am kinda the freshmen of the company and they want me to do it that way ... 
I've tried to do it and they really want the node in aspx...

**Edit:** They actually want to make a listener in the aspx file that is listening to the node.js App ...

Comment: Why don't you do it the other way around?

Comment: Node.js and ASP.NET are two different universes. Even if mixing of them is possible - it could lead to absolutely unexpected bugs. If your company heads are insisting on such a mix... well, good luck.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev that is not true anymore. Take a look at the ASP.NET NodeServices from Steve Sanderson he has presented at the MVP Global Summit last November. There is an amazing video on Channel9.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [ASP.NET + SPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/ASPNET-Events/ASPNET-Fall-Sessions/ASPNET--Spa) Video of Steve Sanderson. He has written NodeServices to mix ASP.NET Core 1, AngularJS and NodeJs.

Absolutely amazing stuff and I'm sure this will improve and push many SPAs.
Maybe you could use the NodeServices for your targets aswell.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**  I solved the problem by including an iFrame in the asp.net website, after I convencing my boss that Asp.Net and Node.js are not compatible ...